# Misunderstanding of Instances and Declarations

Tags: java, variables, object, instance, program-entry-point

I'm a complete novice to Java and in the process of creating the game Snake. In the game I have created a Board class, what this class does is it creates a JFrame for giving a visual representation (to my understanding). My question resides with my lack of understanding of the code. I am not sure what "public static Board board;" does. I had thought it created a static instance of the Board class, although, I believe that this isn't correct.

I am also struggling with the line "board = new Board();", to my understanding this creates an instance of the construct in the Board class, however, I am not sure as to why we assign this to "board".

```
public class Game {

/**
 * @author HyperBlue
 */

//Declaring a static instance/object of Board, this can be accessed from anywhere in the program. The fact that it is static means that it cannot be edited. -- Not sure if right definition
public static Board board;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

//Creates a static object board
board = new Board();

}

}
```

EDIT: Given this, am I right in thinking that `public JFrame frame;` isn't creating a new instance of JFrame called frame? If not, then does it create a variable which I can manipulate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `public static Board board;` declares a variable that can refer to a board. In a way, think of it like a box - you created an empty box. It has nothing in it, but you now have the ability to put something in that box.

Each part of the statement tells you something about the box:

- public : anyone can access this box
- static : the box is associated with the Game *class*, rather than a specific *instance*. For now, just take that to mean there will always be exactly one box, not multiple.
- Board : the "type" of the box is `Board` - only `Board` type things fit in the box.
- board : the name of the box is "`board`". When you want to refer to the contents of this box, you use the name `board`.

You're right in thinking that `board = new Board();` creates an instance of `Board`. Specifically, the `new Board();` portion is the part that makes a new `Board` instance. By saying `board = new Board();`, you are putting that new instance in the box labeled `board` that you declared earlier. From here on out you can refer to the board you created by the name `board`, or outside this class as `Game.board`. It's also important to know that by saying `board = new Board()`, the previous contents of `board`, if there were any, are now lost. You dumped out the box so you could put a new object in it. Obviously here there was nothing in it, but that is something to keep in mind as you move forward in any Object Oriented Language (such as java).

Comment: The difference is important. A variable can *contain* a reference (a type of value) and a variable can - by extension - be used to *refer* to a object that corresponds with the opaque reference value. The term "refer" (verb) describes an action here and is not associated directly with the "reference" (noun), which is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

When you put

```
public static Board board;
```

This implies that in your Java program there is an class level (static) reference which is named as board. It can hold a Board instance.
But until you assign an instance to that reference, it is pointing to nothing. It is just a reference in the memory.

When the code

```
board = new Board();
```

get executed. JVM creates an instance of Board class and then assign that created instance to the board reference that mentioned early.
So finally board reference is now pointing to a Board class instance.
Since it is a static and public one, you can access this from any where with the class name.
e.g.

```
Game.board
```

Answer (score 1):

The first question:

```
public static Board board;
```

So far, you've declared a *reference variable* of type Board with public visibility. It can be accessed anywhere by Game.Board. The static modifier means that it is attached to the class (like static methods that don't require an instance of the class to run i.e. `static void main(String[] args)`). Without assigning anything to the reference with =, it's just an allocation in memory for a reference. It doesn't point to anything. But it will after main executes.

The second question.

```
board = new Board();
```

In java, the right side of any equals sign (=) is evaluated first, so `new Board()` is the first thing that happens. It creates a new object in memory of type Board and calls the default constructor of the board class (presumably setting all instance variables to default values. Finally, the reference to the object, the thing that points to it, is assigned to the board variable. So now, `board.myMethod();` would call the method myMethod of the Board class for the particular instance of it referred to by board.

It sounds esoteric, but it is important. Also, sometimes these steps are combined:

```
Human bob = new Human(); //default constructor (bob.name() == "name")
Human alice = new Human("alice"); //different constructor (alice.name() == "alice")
```

Just as an example.